# Extract HTML from a WebView

Tags: java, javascript, android

I want to extract only the Table (TagName: tbody) from the following Webpage: http://info.tam.ch/custom/stpl_klw.php

But it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

(I used this Tutorial: http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/)

I tried this:

```
public class Stundenplan extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Context myApp = this; 
    class MyJavaScriptInterface  
    {  
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")  
        public void showHTML(String html)  
        {  
            new AlertDialog.Builder(myApp)  
                .setTitle("HTML")  
                .setMessage(html)  
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)  
            .setCancelable(false)  
            .create()  
            .show();  
        }  
    }  

    final WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);  
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");  
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
        @Override  
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
        {  
            browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");  
        }  
    });  

    browser.loadUrl("http://info.tam.ch/custom/stpl_klw.php"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The html of the referenced page does not contain a `<tbody>` element. The *Stundenplan* is a normal `<table>` element.

Comment: I replaced the tbody with table, but it doesn't help...
It just loads the whole Page.

Comment: And after 3 sec the App has a Force Close.

But if I change the color to red it works:
browser.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = 'red'; " +  "})()");
(http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/)

I think it has something to do with the javascript. But i don't get it...